# ColdFusion query of query strange type cast

Tags: coldfusion, qoq

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="LOCAL.modello">
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    modelliDelMarchio 
WHERE 
    marchioid = #ARGUMENTS.marchioid#  
    AND tipologia = #ARGUMENTS.tipo# 
    AND nome = '#ARGUMENTS.nome#'
</cfquery>
```

I have an error on the last query line.

It's:

> Query Of Queries runtime error. Comparison exception while executing
>   =. Unsupported Type Comparison Exception: The = operator does not support comparison between the following types:  Left hand side
>   expression type = "STRING". Right hand side expression type = "LONG".

I swear that:

- ARGUMENTS.nome IS a string (I tried with javacast, too!)
- modelliDelMarchio is a valid DB query, containing real data. "nome" is a varchar.

My version is 9.0.1.

Comment: Try using `<cfqueryparam value="#arguments.nome#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />` and see if that helps. It's a good idea to get into the habit of using `cfqueryparam` everywhere. :)

Comment: Also, are you sure that it is `nome` that is causing the error and not one of the other two comparisons? Have you tried putting all three variables into `cfqueryparam`?

Comment: s992 has a very good point - nothing in the error you've posted says that "nome" is the problem, and with the info provided it seems more likely that "marchioid" or "tipologia" are the culprits. Use cfqueryparam for _all_ of them, and if you still get the error, do `<cfdump var=#arguments# />` to see what each of the values are.

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions, can you post 1) a dump of the query types ie `getMetaData(yourQoQ)` and 2) the `cfargument` declarations - as well as the actual values used in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `cfqueryparam` all of your values. If you can't (or don't want to), then you need to write your expressions like so:

```
marchioid = '#Arguments.marlchioid#'
```

If you leave the quotes off and don't use `cfqueryparam`, the SQL engine will treat those values as either a numeric or boolean value. Strings *must* be in quotes, or `cfqueryparam`s in order to be treated as strings.